# What does HTTP Response Code 1003 means?

Tags: apache, http, tomcat

Would anyone please tell me what does HTTP response code 1003 means. I tried googling it but unable to find a correct answer

Comment: Sounds custom. The various specs go into the 500's. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: I already checked this URL and i am unable to find that error code.

Comment: It's not a valid HTTP error code. What server is returning it? Are you sure it's an HTTP status code, and not just an error code being returned?

Answer (score 15):

Its a **non-standard** response code. Companies like **Cloudflare** use it to specify that the direct IP access is not allowed for this request.

I got this when i tried accessing 80 port of some IP which was a part of Cloudflare. But this does not mean that all 1003 responses mean the same. "Non Standard" :P

Comment: This is actually correct. For example, quizlet.com's IP is 104.16.14.221 but it returns a 1003 when you attempt to visit it. It also states Direct IP connection is disallowed.

Answer (score 5):

[HTTP redirect location does not exist](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/search.102/b32259/ulrcodes.htm)

It is not a standard code but something used by Oracles crawler (?!)

Comment: We dont use oracle anywhere. The thing is when tomcat is hanged then we get Unknown Response Code 1003. But when i google i dont get much information about this type of error.

Comment: Thx :D @fear_matrix Ok than i have no idea. Maybe you could contact the tomcat developers?